# How to pass br to the content attribute or within p tag via graphql query

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When i add `<br/>` inside the content property or pass to `<p>` tag, it's reflecting as text. I wish to break the line passing `<br>` into the content

Below are things i tried, both didn't work

```
<p>{item.description}</p>
<Text content={item.description} />
//Text is a component to output content within a p tag
```

json data as below

```
{
  "description": "Add some break <br/> to this line"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) is what you need here to display your json data as html.

You could do something like this

```
<Text 
 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.description }} 
/>
```